# Make absolute div height 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with position relative and 2 child divs (left and right) with absolute positioning.

Left `div` should be of `height: 100%` and right `div` content changes dynamically. Now when I scroll left child remains smaller (not 100%) and right `div` had its height.

There is horizontal navigation-bar on top of parent div. I tried with `bottom: 0`, `position: fixed`, but results are not good.

```
.left-sidebar {
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: #B3E5FC;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 29%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px 0px grey;
    height: 92vh;
    position: absolute;
}

.right-content{
    display: inline-block;
   // height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    min-width: 66%;
}

.main-parent {
    position: relative;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, can you provide us with your code (portions, if you will)? HTML/CSS.

Comment: You can use the `vh` and `vw` css units. `100vh` will be the total height of the screen.

Comment: tried with 100vh also, not worked .

Comment: And where's the HTML?

Comment: i had made backbone components as left and right content . those are styled through css . So no html direct code is there .

Comment: How can we help you if you don't give us almost any information?